# Making a Piecewise Function into a single expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A phone company gives a 25.00 dollar flat fee up to 200 minutes then .07 dollars for every minute afterwards.
Build a function to find the price of any amount of minutes.
Not in a piecewise function, but in a single expression.
The closest I got was  B = (.07x) + 25 
where B is equal to the final price/charge and x is equal to the amount of minutes over 200.
How can I put this entire thing into a expression without using a piecewise function?

Comment: Does $1/2$ of a minute over $200$ cost $(1/2)(0.07)$? If not, what relevant functions are available in your computer language?

Comment: Two ideas: 

1) Use a step function like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavyside_function

2) Get creative with the $\max$ function where $\max(a,b)$ equals the larger of the two numbers $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y$ is the total number of minutes used. If this is the input, we need a little trick to bypass the natural (and better) "if $y\le 200$ then $25$ else $\dots$." We can use this:
$$25+\frac{(y-200)+\sqrt{(y-200)^2}}{2}(0.07).$$
Further tricks may be needed if fractional extra minutes are rounded up to the nearest integer. Details depend on the basic functions available. For example, in many computer languages, integer division, giving integer quotient and remainder, is available. That can be used to take care of rounding up.